# How do I use WL.Client.getID() properly?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to get the ID of a mobile phone where my hybrid worklight (v6.2) app is running on and the app is hanging on the following code:

```
    WL.Logger.log("About to getID...");
    WL.Client.getID({onSuccess : function(o) {
        WL.Logger.log("getID: " + o);
        devID = o.deviceID;
    }, onFailure : function(e) {
        WL.Logger.log("Error getting ID: " + e);
    }});
    WL.Logger.log("After getID...");
```

I see the "About to getID" output in the LogCat log, but that is it.  I never see the onSuccess logging nor the onFailure logging. And the "After getID" logging never appears either.

From reading the Knowledge center documentation, it doesn't appear this method is making a call back to the Worklight server at all. This has failed both in an Android emulator and on an Android device.

Any suggestions/insight to get this method to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will look at the API reference for Worklight 6.2, you will see there is no such API method as `WL.Client.getID`: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Client.html?cp=SSZH4A_6.2.0%2F10-0-0-1-6

There is however `WL.Device.getID`: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html%23getID

Comment: Good catch Idan.  I must have been messing with some other Client methods and missed changing it.  It works now, thanks!